# Using data from a MySQL database in a form builder app

Tags: mysql, forms, jotform

Are there any form builder apps (like Jotform or Zoho Forms) that allow data to be imported to be used in the fields in the form.  I would like to pre-fill a dropdown box dynamically from a MySQL database.  Any changes to the data in the database should be reflected in the options in the dropdown box.

Thanks